# traversing the DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a lyrics website for one of my own projects and I've run into some problems with jQuery. I'm able to get the name of the artist and the song, but the lyrics are encapsulated in this div that's been pretty difficult to extract the data from. I'm posting the HTML example, my code, and one iteration from the for loop that is being logged.

Essentially, I'm trying to pull in all the lyrics within the div with the inline styles but the object i'm printing to the console takes the form of the object I am showing below. I figured I could just do (this.prev().data()) within the map function but it doesn't seem to work. Any insight or references I could refer to on how to parse this the correct way would be greatly appreciated..!

Thank you!

HTML

```
<div id="main">
<div class="...">...</div>
<h2>ARTIST</h2>
<div class="...">...</div>
<b>"SONG"</b>
<br>
<br>
<div style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">
    <!--start of lyrics -->
    "
    lyric1"
    <br>
    "
    lyric2"
    <br>
    "
    lyric3"
    <br>
    "lyric4"
    etc...
    <!-- end of lyrics -->
</div>
```

CODE

```
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var artist, song, lyrics;
        var json = { artist : "", song : "", lyrics : []};

        $('#main').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            title = data.find('h2').text().replace(' LYRICS','');
            artist = data.find('b').text().replace(/["]+/g, '');
            var lines = data.children().eq(6).children().map(function() {
                console.log(this)
                console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<")
            });
        })
    }
})
```

})

an item from the map function printed by console.log

```
{ type: 'tag',
      name: 'br',
      attribs: {},
      children: [],
      next:
       { data: '\nI remember you was conflicted, misusing your influence\r\n',
         type: 'text',
         next:
          { data: ' end of lyrics ',
            type: 'comment',
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Circular],
            parent: [Object] },
         prev: [Circular],
         parent:
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Object],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] } },
      prev:
       { data: '\nWe want the funk',
         type: 'text',
         next: [Circular],
         prev:
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'br',
            attribs: {},
            children: [],
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         parent:
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Object],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] } },
      parent:
       { type: 'tag',
         name: 'div',
         attribs: { style: 'margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;' },
         children:
          [ bunch of objects within arrays and one [Circular] ]
         next:
          { data: '\r\n\r\n',
            type: 'text',
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Circular],
            parent: [Object] },
         prev:
          { data: '\r\n\r\n',
            type: 'text',
            next: [Circular],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] },
         parent:
          { type: 'tag',
            name: 'div',
            attribs: [Object],
            children: [Object],
            next: [Object],
            prev: [Object],
            parent: [Object] } } }
```

Comment: So, basically all you need is lyrics text including new lines characters (`<br>`s)?

Comment: The actual website would be nice too, for an example.

Comment: Trying to get pull lyrics off from here http://www.azlyrics.com/

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to get the lyrics text without any newline characters and breaks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `contents()` to get the text nodes and you want to use map() to get it into an array format. Returning `null` excludes the line from the array.

```js
var elems = $('#main').children().eq(6).contents().clone();
elems.find("br").remove();
var text = elems.map( function () { 
    var ln = $.trim($(this).text().replace(/["\\n]/g,"")); 
    return (ln.length) ? ln : null;
}).get();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="...">...</div>
  <h2>ARTIST</h2>
  <div class="...">...</div>
  <b>"SONG"</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">
    <!--start of lyrics -->
    "
    lyric1"
    <br>
    "
    lyric2"
    <br>
    "
    lyric3"
    <br>
    "lyric4"
    <!-- end of lyrics -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help epascarello--really appreciate it !  I'm pretty new to jQuery but I keep running into this problem when I try to use the $.method() notation as shown below: var ln = $.trim($(this).text().replace(/["\\n]/g,""));
                ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function